# RevMob SDK error

Tags: android, sdk, revmob

Since yesterday I'm trying to install RevMob's SDK and I'm getting constant error with this line:

```
RevMob revmob = RevMob.start(this, REVMOB_APP_ID);
        revmob.showFullscreen(this);
```

And the error is:

```
REVMOB_APP_ID cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I don't understand where the problem is because I have set the app id and copy pasted all the xml code that they provided still no luck. I'm literally pulling my hair out right now, its very frustrating.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

use your revmob app id..... For example: 49830398bbfid392

It has to be in wrapped with `""` like this: `"49830398bbfid392"`